# Unable to create a 'DBContext'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

i have the following error message:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider.

I get this when I try to add my first migration.
How can I fix that?

This is my context class:

```cs
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

And this is my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
    options
        .UseMySql( builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext"), new MariaDbServerVersion("10.5.18-MariaDB") )
);
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserManager, UserManager>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.Run();
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem the last day, and I found that it's just a library compatibility issue.

in addition to having the "dotnet ef 8.0.0" setup globally while using .net8.0, this was all the extra libraries I installed to get the EF working.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 8.0.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 8.0.0
MySql.Data  Unknown 8.2.0
MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.10
```

and this is what made it work.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.14
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 7.0.14
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.14
MySql.Data  Unknown 8.2.0
MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
```

Your DbContext has a constructor that accepts DbContextOptions.

From your code, I was unable to locate this piece of code where you load options parameter.

You can try to override the `OnConfiguring` method to build your options in your `MyContext` Class

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build();
            string connString = config.GetConnectionString("DbCoreConnectionString");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString); //Or whatever DB you are using
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I used a `--verbose` and noticed that there is an issue with the mapping

```
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindCollectionMapping(RelationalTypeMappingInfo info, Type modelType, Type providerType, CoreTypeMapping elementMapping)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.<>c.<FindMappingWithConversion>b__8_0(ValueTuple`4 k, RelationalTypeMappingSource self)
```

The root issue was caused by a `string` property of a model explicitly mapped via IEntityTypeConfiguration to an integer (like `.HasColumnType("int"))`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message and main error was in my primary key name because I created primary key with different name like GuestId so I have to define manually [Key] attribute schema on GuestId.
Try to check your Class primary property.